# Anyone else that has changed to using OneDrive and having issues with Visual Studio trying to reach out to the old path?

Tags: onedrive, visual-studio

We are starting to use OneDrive, but Visual Studios still tries to use C:\users\username\documents instead of the new C:\users\username\onedrive folder\documents folder.

So now the Visual studio projects are having issues. Wanted to see if anyone else has dealt with this process and had an info.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling Visual Studio?

Comment: I have not, would be preferable not to have to reinstall on everyone using visual studio in our environment, but if there is no other option then we will not have a choice xD